# modx : can't upload image or file after MOD Xupdate

Tags: image, upload, modx

I updated several modX sites today. They were quite old.

Now, when i want to upload an image on any of thoose websites, i can't. The uploader can"t finish the upload. **The uploaded size is bigger than the expected size and the upload is incomplete** :
[watch the error : 1 image worths 1000 words sometimes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOSMK.jpg)

I have this in all the modX site since update.
I tried clearing the cache without effects. Any idea how to solve this ?

Thanks

Thomas

Comment: Probably related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/2184513/1531971 but it depends on how this API interacts with PHP. Anyway, you have some research to do.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have tried to visit the system settings?
Section "Core", subsection "file system". Perhaps, you need to change the value of the "upload_maxsize" key.
I have the default "10485760"

[System Setting Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Raduo.jpg)

Comment: It's also possible to delete files inside the cache folder, if you did not. I do not mean clearing the cache in the admin panel, but using FTP or the file manager of your hosting.